# How to serialize animation state?

Tags: unity, animation, serialization

In Unity, I have an Animator on a character.

Upon saving/loading the game, I want to preserve the pose and animation state the character is in.

However, I can see no way to read/write all the data from the Animator/Animation Controller in such a way that I can store it in and retrieve it from a binary file.

Is there a non-obvious way to achieve this?

Comment: What information do you need? I'd suspect you'd want the current state and playhead time within the current clip (on each layer) which the API exposes for you to read or set as needed. Where did you run into trouble storing or loading this info?

Comment: Playhead time... That was the issue. Seems I lacked the proper terminology to figure this one out.